# Why am I still receiving a 'NoneType' error when it should be resolved?

Tags: python, rest, nonetype

I am calling data where some cells might be blank and attempting to filter it based on certain criteria.

```
if data is not None:
   if data <= 50000:
     print(data)
```

I am getting an error that states that 'NoneType' data is not comparable to an integer.  Why am I still receiving this error even after filtering out NoneTypes with the first line of code above?

Edit for clarification: The code is actually set up like this, which pulls data from the Polygon api data feed (https://polygon.io/docs/#getting-started).

```
tickers = api.polygon.all_tickers()
for ticker in tickers:
   if ticker.prevDay['c'] >= 20:
     company = api.polygon.company(ticker.ticker)
     if company.marketcap is not None:
        if company.marketcap <= 500000000:
           print(ticker.ticker)
```

This will grab all available equities from the data feed, which have certain attributes like "ticker" (returns symbol) or "prevDay" (returns previous day open, high, low, or close).

I believe the problem is that not all equities have the 'marketcap' data field populated, so iterating over them returns the 'NoneType' error message.  I'm typing this off of memory so do not have the exact error message handy but will update later.

Comment: Can you post what 'data' is? Also the actual error message you receive would be good too.

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve] for questions seeking debugging help

Comment: Edit the question to show the full traceback as properly formatted text. Probably the error is not caused by the shown code. And show how "data" is set.

Comment: Is `data` a scalar or an array of some sort (Pandas series, NumPy array etc)?

Comment: Also, on which line is that error occurring?

Comment: Why post the question before you have the relevant information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `data` is some sort of iterable (list, dataframe, matrix).
If that's true, then the first conditional is comparing data to None. Any iterable, even one that contains only None's is not None. So the first conditional is true.

But the 2nd conditional (if `data` is, say, a numpy array) is elementwise. So I'm guessing that one or more of the elements in the numpy array is None and that's why it fails.

If this is really a numpy array, then do it the numpy way:

```
data_nonnan = data[np.where(~np.isnan(data))]
print(data_nonnan[data_nonnan < 50000])
```

Comment: The first and second `data` should both be the same. I edited my example to clarify, but `data` is `company.marketcap` which should return an integer value for the market capitalization of the ticker currently being iterated on. Since that is an elementwise value, should the `if company.marketcap is not None` statement be able to filter out the None results?

Comment: @standard If company is a class and marketcap is a field in that class, and is not an interable, then that should work. But if company is a dictionary, and marketcap is an element in that dictionary but might not be there, then this code would throw a Nonetype exception because you are trying to access an element in the dictionary that might not exist. You have to check for existence.

Comment: I believe company is a dictionary. In that case, I'm assuming I would run `if marketcap in company.keys()` instead of `is not None`.  What if the marketcap key exists for a given ticker, but it is missing a value?

Comment: you'll need `if 'marketcap' in company.keys()` (marketcap in quotes). The keyword `and` short circuits any subsequent clauses if the first clause is false, so you are safe doing:

`if ('b' in d.keys()) and (d['b'] is not None) and (d['b'] < 5000):`